# What will be the value of resistor to be connected in series with freewheeling diode if brake coil is 110 V DC

Tags: resistors, diode-clamp

In order to quickly off the brake, what will be the value of resistor to be connected in series with freewheeling diode? Brake coil is 110 V DC.

Answer (score 1):

The peak voltage across the resistor will be the coil operating current times the resistance.

So if your coil is 100mA then 1K will allow the coil voltage to go from +110V to -100V. Your switching device will thus see 210V.

The higher the resistance, the faster the field will collapse, but the higher the voltage the switching device will experience (if the resistor value is made **really** high, there may be a lot of ringing and/or the coil may break down from excessive voltage).

So, pick an acceptable voltage, and calculate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast response of a elecromechanical brake you shoul use MOV instead of a freewheeling diode or a freewheeling diode with series zener diode.

http://machinedesign.com/news/suppression-circuits-clutches-and-brakes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI6riM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>